# Silverlight + Entity framework code first + DomainService + partial class

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, ef-code-first, partial-classes

I have silverlight project with entityes
thisis my table class

```
 public class OrderHeader : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string OrderId{get;set;}
}
```

And I have

```
 public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<OrderHeader> OrderHeaders { get; set; }

}
```

I have domain service

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class ShopService : DomainService
{
    [Invoke]
    public OrderHeader GetOrderHeader()
    {
        using (var db = new DataBaseContext())
        {
            return db.OrderHeader.FirstOrdefault(o=>o.OrderId == "123";
         }
    }
}
```

In my SL app I want use OrderHeader as partial class. something like

```
public partial class OrderHeader
{
   public DateTime LoadDate{get;set;}
}

private void LoadData()
{
  ShopServiceContext context = new ShopServiceContext();
  context.GetOrderHeader(OrderLoaded, null)
}
private void OrderLoaded(InvokeOperation<OrderHeader> result)
{
   var loadedOrder = result.Value; //load order this is my partial class from SL app
   loadedOrder.Loaddate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

can I create somethink Like this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. First create a new Silverlight class library to hold your entities for the Silverlight projects. Then, add your entity (OrderHeader) into this project with "Add As Link".

For the properties (or other code parts) to be available only at the Silverlight side, you can use compiler directives like below:

```cs
#if SILVERLIGHT
    // Do silverlight stuff 
    public DateTime LoadDate{get;set;}
#endif
```

After this, your entities will be compiled conditionally different for Silverlight projects.

Comment: on the setter don't you have to Notify that the property has changed ?

Comment: If you'll bind this property to a Silverlight component or make validation at the Silverlight side, then you need to fire notifypropertychanged.
Your property may be like this:  

        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set
            {
                if (_title != value)
                {
                    _title = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Title"));    
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: I use Notufy. I was write simple example. Where I can find option "Add As Link"(VS 2012)

Comment: Right click on project -> Add -> Existing Item. You can see "Add as Link" in the combo attached to Add button.